# Determining distribution based on first three even moments

Tags: probability, distributions, self-study

Given that $E(X^2) = 1, E(X^4) = 3, E(X^6) = 9$, determine all possible distributions of X.

I'm sure there's some insight I'm missing here. I noted that X is mesokurtic, so it's *possibly* normal... but I calculated the even moments of the standard normal, and I don't think a purely scale transformation of Z fits: $E(Z^2)= 1, E(Z^4) = 3, E(Z^6) = 15$.

A hint towards the correct answer would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you learned about moment generating functions, characteristic functions, or cumulant-generating functions?  They sometimes can be helpful in such cases.

Comment: @whuber, I know MGFs and CGFs, but I'm not familiar with characteristic functions (or measure theory, if this problem needs it!). I thought on your hint for a little bit, but I'm unable to puzzle out anything beyond the trivial "the coefficients of $t^2$, $t^4$, and $t^6$ in the Taylor expansion of the MGF of X are..."

Comment: The mgf *etc.* typically provide universal inequalities which, when they become equalities, determine specific extreme distributions. This kind of question typically is answered, then, by suspecting the data identify a unique distribution (in this case, of $Y=X^2$) and then guessing what that distribution must be and checking that guess.

Comment: @whuber, I've identified two functions which fit the bill:
a) Y is gamma with $\alpha = 1/2, \beta=2$
b) Y is a discrete RV which takes values 0 and 3 with probability 2/3 and 1/3.

Comment: On another verification, the gamma function doesn't fit the bill, leaving me with the humble discrete Y as my only idea.

Comment: That's right--the Gamma doesn't work.  Now you just have to characterize the random variables $X$ corresponding to that $Y=X^2.$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135894/discussion-between-aditya-n-and-whuber).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a linear combination of $X^2,X^4$ and $X^6$: $$g(X)=aX^6+bX^4+cX^2$$

Choose scalars $a,b,c$ such that $E\left[g(X)\right]=0$ and $g(X)\ge 0$ almost surely. This would imply $g(X)=0$ almost surely (see e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/897876/321264), based on which one can determine the distribution of $X$ from the given information.

Observe that $0\le (X^3-3X)^2=X^6-6X^4+9X^2$ almost surely, and $E\left[X^6-6X^4+9X^2\right]=0$, so one such choice of $(a,b,c)$ is $(1,-6,9)$. I am not sure if this is the only choice.

Therefore, the distribution of $X$ must satisfy $$(X^3-3X)^2=X^2(X^2-3)^2=0 \quad,\text{ a.s. }$$